# php MVC without routes

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, routes

I would like to know if it's possible to create an mvc project in php without to use routes.
For example:

I have the controller strumenti.php

```
class Strumenti
{
    public function index()
    { 
        require 'application/models/strumentimodel.php';
        $strumenti_model=new StrumentiModel("r");
        $strumenti = $strumenti_model->getAllInstruments();
        require 'application/views/_templates/header.php';
        require 'application/views/strumenti/index.php';
        require 'application/views/_templates/footer.php';
    }

    public function deleteStrumento($nome)
    {   
        if (isset($nome)) {
            require 'application/models/strumentimodel.php';
            $strumenti_model=new StrumentiModel("r");  
            $strum=$strumenti_model->deleteStrumentoDaArray($nome);   
        }
        header('location: 'mysite/strumenti/index');
    }
}
```

and my model strumentimodel.php

```
class StrumentiModel
{
    private $handle;

    function __construct($mode) {
        try {
            $this->handle = fopen(STRUMENTI, "$mode");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit('Errore di apertura file');
        }
    }

    public function getAllInstruments()
    {
        $csv = array();
        $lines = file(STRUMENTI);

        foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
        {
            $csv[$key] = str_getcsv($value,";");
        }
        return $csv;
    }
    public function deleteStrumentoDaArray($nome)
    {
        //array con tutti gli strumenti
        $strum=$this->getAllInstruments();

        for($i=0;$i<count($strum);$i++){
            if(in_array($nome,$strum[$i])){
                $this->indice=$i;
            }
        }
        unset($strum[$this->indice]);
        return $strum;
    }
}
```

and this is a View (index.php)

```
<div>
            <h3>Strumenti</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>nome</td>
                        <td>modello</td>
                        <td>tipo</td>
                        <td>costo</td>
                        <td>Elimina</td>
                        <td>Modifica</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php for ($riga=1;$riga<count($strumenti);$riga++):  ?>
                        <tr>
                            <?php for ($colonna=0; $colonna<count(current($strumenti)); $colonna++):  ?>
                                <td><?php echo $strumenti[$riga][$colonna];?></td>
                            <?php endfor; ?>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo mysite/strumenti/deleteStrumento/' . $strumenti[$riga][0]; ?>">x</a></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo mysite/strumenti/index ?>">Index</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>



        </div>
```

If I would call the model from the controller there is no problems even without routes, but I can I call the controller from the view without routes?

In my example I call it so from a link:

```
<a href="<?php echo mysite/strumenti/deleteStrumento/' . $strumenti[$riga][0]; ?>">x</a>
```

The structure is: class/method/paramether

Is it possible to call the class method without routes?

Comment: If you create mysite/strumenti/xyz means you a route or directory path, so do you want access to controllers with directories?

Comment: in form submit option to call the controller function after that you will change the controller in that end.

Answer (score 6):

"Routes" have nothing particularly to do with MVC. A "route" as it is colloquially understood is some function/class/code that resolves a **URL** to an executable piece of code, usually a controller. Well, you can have that "for free" with PHP's standard behaviour by using URLs like `/controllers/foo-controller.php`, in which is code which will execute a controller. Your controller doesn't even need to be a class, it just needs to be something which receives a request and can decide which model actions to invoke and/or what view/response to send.

That's all MVC is about: having a core *model* which contains everything your app can "do", having *views* separately from that which provide a UI for your model, and lastly having a *controller* which acts on user input (here: HTTP requests). That separation is simply so you can adapt your app (the model) to different scenarios easily by swapping out the UI (view) and input handlers (controllers). Nothing in that prescribes the use of classes, routes or anything else.

Comment: The MVC concept is clear for me, but I can I call the right controller's function from a view (for example using a link  /controllers/foo-controller.php ? In this case I call the file but I cannot choose the method/function

Comment: In an HTTP scenario, you never "call a controller's function" at all. At best you create a URL in a view, and the web server resolves that URL to a specific file. Your controller file could contain something like `require 'c.php'; (new C)->action();`. That's basically a poor man's front controller/router. Or the file simply contains code which imports the model and calls something there, making the file itself the "controller function".

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can call controller action from the view, but what the purpose of this.
Also never-ending loop is possible if you call controller action which rendners view that calls this action again.
Please clarify what your purpose.

Comment: If I want to do an action from the view I click a link witch will call a controller (whitch is responsable to do the action). I can call the controller using his filename for ex /controllers/foo-controller.php but how can I call a method/function?

Comment: Use GET parameters. Just add php code after controller class declaration to check if necessary parameters was given. But it will be freaky solution =)

Or... you can handle all requests in entry point and then resolve parameters. But it will be actually routing)))